# Is this a dead-lock or not?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I tried running a couple of (identical but on different data) (nested) stored procedures in parallel on the server and although this works nicely (given proper locking hints) I did end up with the following situation:

[image: deadlock or not?]

To me this looks like spid 116 is blocked by spid 117, while spid 117 is blocked by 116 (well some of its threads are in each case).

For the process to continue I had to manually kill one of them. I'd expect MSSQL to recognize this situation as 'unsolvable' and deadlock one of them.
Funny enough I had this happen twice running (almost) the same tests, albeit on different blocks.

This was on a SQL2017 DEV-Edition with 20 cores and 96Mb ram; the stored procedures involved are fairly complex and involve SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE operations on the same tables (but different records) inside and outside different transactions spread out over the different stored procedures. 
(It sounds worse than it is, really =)

Comment: Include the wait type from the activity monitor was well.

Comment: It looks like some of the threads for SPID 117 are in conflict with 116, try setting your `max degree of parallelism` to 8 in line with the recommendations from MS:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2806535/recommendations-and-guidelines-for-the-max-degree-of-parallelism-confi

Comment: They are blocking each other for sure and slowing themselves down, but it's not a deadlock yet until the database engine officially kills one because it detects the deadlock state.  I agree with MJH, take a look at maxDOP, it might help.  Better yet, if possible create your script to update in smaller batches if possible to avoid locking.

Comment: MAXDOP was indeed what I planned to look at next; if I encounter the same situation again I'll make sure to have a look the wait-types. For now all I can say is that it had been running all night while normally each block would take a couple of minutes only; so it was slightly worse than simply slowing each other down I fear.

Comment: You might want to look at the lock resource to find out what the processes are waiting on, I imagine the wait type will be `WRITELOG` as both operations try to update the log.